# Google Play Services Dependency

Tags: android

When I open my app, it is supposed to take me to the login page for Google or email.  It runs me to the main screen and says update Google Play Services.  I am not sure why this is happening when I am running the latest version -

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.0.0'
```

I switched to just the auth in order to avoid transitive dependency issues. It was not working with the regular gps dependency.

It isn't my code because I have been doing a tutorial..I've checked.

My project builds, but I would like the services to work :-)

Answer (score 0):

In your project level build.gradle add

```
dependencies {
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
}
```

Comment: I have it at 3.1.0.. just tried for 3.0.0. My bad, should have included that.

Comment: Did not..  Haha forgot to mention that.